# Tab Display :Remove the bottom border line

Tags: asp.net, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a WPF application where I need to remove the bottom border line from the tab which is selected so that selected tab follows seamlessly into the page.
I want to remove the red mark show in the image(which is bottom border line) without removing the Tab Panel/Sub Tab Panel .
[image]

I have already set Margin property of the HeaderPanel as
Margin="0,0,4,**-1**"
but it does not solves my problem and the constraint is that my Tab/Sub tab panel cant be transparent /white [image: Desired Output]

Please help.

```
 <Style x:Key="TabControlsample" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="tabScroller" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Style="{StaticResource TabScrollView}">
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" 
                         Margin="2,2,2,0" IsItemsHost="True" 
                        Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: By default, The selected tab doesn't show the Border line in Tabcontrol, I dont know how you are receiving border line..can you show xaml code where you implemented Tabcontrol.

Comment: Hi Anees I hv added the samplecode. Pls have a look.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: No I am still facing problem. Pls let me know if you were able to resolve the issue.